# How to get range of possible returns on market portfolio from two points on minimum variance frontier

Tags: finance, financial-economics

I am revising for an exam in financial economics and have come across this part paper question, which has left me completely stuck:

"Consider a CAPM economy with just three risky assets, A, B, and C with expected rates of return of 10%, 20%, and 10%, respectively. Two portfolios, 1 and 2, are known to lie on the minimum variance frontier. They are defined by the portfolio weights $w_1 = (w^A_1, w^B_1, w^C_1) = (0.6, 0.2, 0.2)$ and $w_2 = (w^A_2, w^B_2, w^C_2) = (0.8, -0.2, 0.4)$  respectively. **What are the minimum and maximum possible values for the expected rate of return on the market portfolio?**"

It is easy to calculate that $E[r_1] = w_1 \cdot (0.6,0.2,0.2) = 0.12$ and $E[r_2] = w_2 \cdot (0.8,-0.2,0.4) = 0.08$ . But as we have no information about the risk-free rate or any of the variances or covariances, I am really stuck here. Any help is much appreciated!

Comment: You should draw a graph of the minimum variance frontier and think how the solution is going to look like. Make an assumption about the covariances of the assets or Rf and solve the question. If you can find several solutions, show it